# R function to filter a variable by the first letter

Tags: r, filter, alphanumeric

I have a variable that is alphanumeric - always starts with a letter and followed by numbers.
Ex. A483, B472, K112

I want to create a dataset with only the variables that start with a certain letter.
Ex. A dataset with only rows that included the variable starting with F.

I tried:

Fonlydata = data %>% filter(variable == "^[F]")

but doesn't work. Could anyone please help? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We can use `substr` to extract the first letter and then use `==`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    filter(substr(variable, 1, 1) == "F")
```

---

Or another option is regex with `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
data %>%
    filter(str_detect(variable, '^F'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `filter` suggests that you are using `dplyr`. This is an example on how to use "normal" R with the buildin `grep` function on the names of a data frame:

```
expl <- data.frame(abs = rnorm(10), bcd = rnorm(10), foo = 1:10, def = rnorm(10), faa = 1:10)
print(expl)
result <- expl[,grep('^f', names(expl))]
print(result)
```